# Trying to convert latitude longitude values in UJIIndoorLoc dataset to degrees

Tags: python, coordinate-system, javascript, convert

I'm trying to convert the latitude and longitude values in [UJIIndoorLoc dataset](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/ujiindoorloc) to degrees. The paper mentions that the data is in UTM from WGS84.

Here is an example of the values given:

- LATITUDE: 4864837.920500003
- LONGITUDE: -7360.497299999

Upon converting these I get values :

```
(lat: 43.76251700390833, lng: 2.6974029749144584)
```

But the result I should be getting should be near Universitat Jaume I in Spain (around 39.992845, -0.068439)

Can someone help me figure out the mapping please ?

Comment: did you figure this out? I have the same issue. thanks

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/162945)

Comment: Your LATITUDE and LONGITUDE values aren't latitude and longitude values

Answer (score 1):

It took me some time to figure this out, but the UJIIndoorLoc dataset is not in UTM (as mentioned by OP), but in Pseudo Mercator (EPSG:3857).

This Python snippet reads the dataset and unprojects it:

```
import pandas as pd
from pyproj import Transformer

transformer = Transformer.from_crs(crs_from=3857, crs_to=4326)

df = pd.read_csv('validationData.csv')
unprojected_df = df.apply(lambda xy: transformer.transform(xy['LONGITUDE'], xy['LATITUDE']), axis=1)
```

The result is:

```
0      (39.9927560407408, -0.06751662935071567)
1     (39.99241246128007, -0.06633040780517456)
2     (39.99245921530593, -0.06624448268125044)
3     (39.99243372020682, -0.06616833072143029)
4    (39.992981338661174, -0.06864475617804247)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can see by csv to map with EPSG:3857 on QGIS
https://epsg.io/3857

So you have better to reprojection and saved as .csv

https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_projections/working_with_projections.html

Good luck

[image]